# Angular Component using Javascript Library function throwing Type Error: is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have written a simple Javascript library to clump together some functions that number of Angular Components need to use. The calcs.js library has f few functions like this in it:

```
function calculateCosts(object) {

  do some stuff.....
  return answer;
}
```

I include the library in my Angular component like this:

```
import * as calc from '../scripts/calcs.js';
```

I then call this function from within my ngInit() like so:

```
ngInit() {
  var costs = calc.calculateCosts(stuff);
}
```

It compiles and upon runtime it throws the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _scripts_calcs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.calculateTotalCosts is not a function
```

Am I doing this correctly? This is the first time I've tried writing my own javascript function library and including it in component, so I may have done something very silly.

I definitely have the correct path in the import, and the correct function name in the component

All help appreciated

Comment: And how do `calcs.js`'s export statements look like?

Comment: @mbojko It is just a file full of functions like above - I don't have any export statements in it

Comment: You need to export `calculateCosts function`. just add `export` before that. like `export function calculateCosts(){..}`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't import what the module isn't exporting. You can simply add `export` statements in your library:

```
export function calculateCosts(object) {
// do some stuff.....
    return answer;
}
```